# Dequeuing as per UITableView and UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I would like to use the dequeue model from UITableView and UICollectionView in my own class, which I will call `CustomControl` here.  My goal is to recycle view controllers rather than views, but I think the principle is the same. My idea for the design is something like:

- The consumer is the `dataSource` of the `CustomControl` instance, `myCustomControl`.
- The consumer tells `myCustomControl` which kind of views it wants to use for a certain string identifier:

  `[myConstomControl registerClass:[UIViewController class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"StandardViewController"];
  [myConstomControl registerClass:[SomeCustomController class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomController"];`
- The `CustomControl` captures this info in an NSDictionary

  `-(void)registerClass:(Class)viewControllerClass forCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {
      [self.classRegister setObject:viewControllerClass forKey:identifier];
  }`
- When `myCustomControl` refreshes, it asks the `datasource` for a controller. The `datasource` dequeues a controller from `myCustomControl`, passing in the type required as a string identifier. 

  `UIViewController *controller = [myCustomControl dequeueViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StandardViewController"];`
- `myCustomControl` either recycles or creates a controller of the type stored in the dictionary and returns it to the `datasource`, where it is customized and returned to `myCustomControl` for display.

I would welcome comment on this pattern but it seems workable to me. I'm not sure though abut the dequeuing part:

- When it comes time to create or re-use a controller for a given string identifier, I will need a separate set of recycled controllers for each identifier, or some other method to recycle the correct controller type. I suppose when the identifier is first registered I can create a custom NSSet to store controllers of that type, but I'm not sure how to label dynamically so I can find it later by identifier. Or should I use a single queue and try to find something of the correct type? This seems like it might have performance implications given the purpose of this pattern.
- How does one create an object of type `Class`?

Answer (score 0):

Have a Mutable Dictionary to hold data. Key being the "Identifier" and  Object is custom object of a new class say reuseInfo.

The custom object can have a class name, array of VC.

Once register method is called, you add a key to the dictionary and create custom class with the class name and empty array (Mutable)

- When Dequeue method is called, get the object for key, check for VC array. If empty create a vc and return.
- Use a subclass of UIViewController for this purpose and have a private property 'isReadyForReuse' and method 'PrepareForReuse'. Write your own logic to determine whether the VC is ready to reuse.
  -In dequeue if the array is present, check for any VC is reusable, if not create a new VC add to the array and then return the VC.
  If reusable, call the method 'prepare for reuse' and return the vc.

The VCs can override the prepare reuse to clean up the Properties and other values.